# Is the time complexity of this code snippet O(n)?

Tags: c, complexity-theory, loops, binary-tree, linked-list

```
struct lists * list_depth[ht];
for(int i=0; i<ht; i++)
    list_depth[i]=NULL;
insert_to_list(&list_depth[0], root);
for( int i = 1; i < ht; i++ )
{
    struct lists * temp = list_depth[i-1];
    while( temp != NULL )
    {
        if(temp->node->llink!=NULL)
            insert_to_list(&list_depth[i],temp->node->llink);
        if(temp->node->rlink!=NULL)
            insert_to_list(&list_depth[i],temp->node->rlink);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}
```

What is the time complexity of the snippet? Since the loops are nested, does it have n^2 complexity?
It's a program to create a list of elements at every depth of a binary tree.
I think it's O(n). Am I right? [N being the number of elements]

Comment: Why do you think it's O(n)?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is O(n * log(n)) because you are traversing the length of the tree, which is O(log(n)), n times.